# video not loaded when setting src in script

Tags: javascript, html, video

I just copied some sample from book HTML5 Canvas, which loads video in the javascript and show that video on Canvas;

the Basic code is as following:

```
videoElement = document.createElement("video");
videoDiv = document.createElement("div");
document.body.appendChild(videoDiv);
videoDiv.appendChild(videoElement);

videoElement.setAttribute("src", "url to the video");
videoElement.addEventListener("canplaythrough", videoLoaded, false);
```

suppose the videoLoaded should be called after when loading video, but it isn't;

I checked it in firebug, it shows that the browser just keeps loading the video, but no content fetched;

I just upgrade firefox from v17 to v18.

And it worked in V17.

Could some help me out of this? thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the source without the "setAttribute" function. You will also need to enable the controls in order for most browsers to actual run.

Replace:

```
videoElement.setAttribute("src", "url to the video");
```

with:

```
videoElement.src = 'http://static.bouncingminds.com/ads/5secs/baileys_5sec.mp4';
videoElement.width = 320;
videoElement.height = 240;
videoElement.controls = true;
```

There are [other options](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_video.asp) you can apply to the video tag, one of which I'd suggest considering is "preload"

All works on Chrome with the above code... I also suggest not relying on HTML5 as all browsers do not support. There are a few good fallback options such as [VideoJS](http://videojs.com/) and [JWPlayer](http://www.longtailvideo.com/jw-player/) which will play what browsers support rather than forcing HTML5 or Flash

***edit**: I just noticed "FireFox" -- replace the .mp4 video with something else, FF doesn't play well with mp4's*

Comment: I tried video.src and set video.preload = true, not working. the FF still keeps loading but no content get.

Comment: Excellent -- there is actually no preload="true" option in the tag. "auto" "metadata" "none"

By using "none", it is the same thing as it just not being present at all in the tag.